# shadowbox.js not working, only opening properly half the time

Tags: javascript, popup, shadowbox

I am using the shadowbox.js code to pop open product details on my site. It works great about half the time. When it's not functioning properly, it opens the link page in the same window. For example, if you click on any of the image boxes at the top "Boombastic/Boombastic Plus" -or- "Team Pack Diamondista", it should pop up a window in the shadowbox.
http://www.teamsportsplanet.com/sharedfiles/softballhome.php?sport=softball

`<img src="images/LandingPage_Softball_TSP_teampack_01.jpg" /></a><a href="team-packs/softball-team-uniform-packages_2.html" title="Softball Team Packs" target="_new" rel="shadowbox" alt="Order Team Softball Uniform Packages">`

They SHOULD be popping up in a shadowbox, with this page inside:
http://www.teamsportsplanet.com/sharedfiles/team-packs/softball-team-uniform-packages_2.html

I don't know what it going on with this and wonder if it's just something in the JavaScript code itself.

Comment: You might have to provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what's going on without the portion of your js that initializes shadowbox, but...

... since the box loads ok but not with the url you're expecting, make sure that

```
content:
```

attribute is getting the correct url as it's value.

Per [their docs](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/api.html#buildobject):

```
**content** The value of the link's href attribute
```

Check that first.

Comment: Here's the actual javascript code used for the shadowbox:

http://www.teamsportsplanet.com/sharedfiles/js/shadowbox.js

Comment: I'm just so confused - I've never worked with javascript before and am trying to figure out code that somebody else set up. Let me know if that shadowbox.js helps or if there's any other code I might need to post - thanks so much!

Comment: that's ok, just post the part that calls the shadowbox

Comment: Ok, so this is the image link that pops up the shadowbox: 
<img src="images/LandingPage_Softball_TSP_teampack_01.jpg" /></a><a href="team-packs/softball-team-uniform-packages_2.html" title="Softball Team Packs" target="_new" rel="shadowbox" alt="Order Team Softball Uniform Packages">

Comment: ok, but add it to your question and format and what url SHOULD load into that box

Comment: I think I figured out the issue - if the link is clicked before the page fully loads, then it pops it into a new page instead of the javascript driven shadowbox. Any tips on how to speed-up the page load time or pre-load javascript? thanks!

Comment: if that's really the case, try calling the shadowbox in the window.onload event instead of the usual jquery document.ready. Speeding up page load is really beyond the scope of this question I think. Try placing all the javascript files/links to them at the bottom of the page. Maybe even test it with the shadowbox minified and placed directly in the page, right before you call it.